# Get sibling by class attribute and then textContent

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do this in the console:

```
foo = document.querySelectorAll('#authCreateAcctUsernameInput')
```

Then an object like this is returned:
foo

```
[<input type=​"text" maxlength=​"70" id=​"authCreateAcctUsernameInput" name=​"userName" autocomplete=​"off" autocapitalize=​"off" autocorrect=​"off">​]
```

The html looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <label class="userName" for="authCreateAcctUsernameInput">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="70" id="authCreateAcctUsernameInput" name="userName" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
    <span id="authCreateAcctUsernameErrorTxt" class="errorMSG" style="display: block;">Please enter a valid email address.</span></fieldset>
```

And what I want to to get the content of the last element there ("Please enter a valid email address") so I tried this:

```
$(foo).siblings('.errorMSG').textContent
```

But that returned undefined. Same for `.innerHTML` and `.value`

How would I grab the textContent of a sibling based on the class value of that sibling (so get the textContent of sibling with class errorMSG)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is mixing `jQuery` with javascript.

Do this to get the text.

```
$(foo).siblings('.errorMSG').text();
```

`textContent` is a property of `DOM` object, but you have a jQuery Object. So call jquery functions on it.

Bellow are the different DOM Object properties & there equivalent Jquery Object functions

```
DOMObject.value         jqueryObject.val()
DOMObject.innerHTML     jqueryObject.html()
DOMObject.textConetnt   jqueryObject.text()
```

And many others.

Comment: Yes! Thank you plan to accept that shortly. Curious, is there a way that's nearly as simple not using jquery?

Comment: @DougFirr sorry I didn't get what do you want?

Comment: Thanks again. To rephrase, I only used jquery after Googling "get sibling based on class". All the results pointed to jquery. Just wanted to confirm there was no simple and equivalent way to achieve my goal without using jquery and js only?

Comment: @DougFirr I think you can, end of the day, jquery is JS lib only, but it could cause a lot of effort.

Comment: @DougFirr You could use `nextElementSibling` property!